# document.location.reload() não re-envia post igual ao atualizar a página

Tags: php, javascript

Eu tive que fazer umas alterações em uma parte do sistema, e nessa parte antes eu estava passando os dados só por GET, mas agora posso passar tanto por GET quanto por POST, mas estou tendo um problema com o `document.location.reload()` que não re-envia os dados do POST como os que estão no GET. Deveria ter o mesmo efeito de eu apertar o F5 que re-envia os dados.

Alguém sabe como posso tentar pelo menos solucionar isso?

Não sei se é necessário, mas no `backend` estou usando `php`

Comment: Creio que pelo fato de o GET ser passado pela URL, ao atualizar, os dados permaneciam o mesmo lá. Já o post, os dados do formulários geralmente são perdidos com refreshs.

Comment: Provavelmente os campos (textFields) estão sendo limpos quando vc dá o primeiro submit.

Answer (score 3):

A [documentação da MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location.reload) sobre o método `Location.reload()` não é clara sobre isso, mas esse método **apenas recarrega a página atual utilizando o método** `GET`. A ação de chamar esse método é quase a mesma de clicar no botão de *refresh* do navegador.

Acredito que com isso, você tenha as seguintes opções:

- Criar um [form](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_form.asp) invisível com os parâmetros do `POST` e realizar um
  submit nele utilizando JavaScript;
- Transformar os parâmetros do `POST` em
  [parâmetros de URL](http://www.guiadophp.yoonix.com.br/2010/06/16/passar-parametros-ph/) (`?param=valor`) e realizar uma nova requisição `GET`;
- Utilizar [AJAX](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/AJAX_(programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o));

---

Pergunta semelhante do SOEn:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13476006/javascript-location-reload-is-losing-post-data

Comment: Então, esses links eu já havia até visto antes, mas ainda não consegui, mas ainda assim agradeço. E a ação não é tão a mesma assim, pois quando clico no botão refresh ainda assim passa os parametros do post.

Comment: Editei corrigindo a afirmação do botão refresh. De qualquer forma, utilizando um form invisivel você não consegue atingir o que você quer?

Answer (score 1):

Amigo. Não entendi muito bem seu questionamento. Desculpe-me caso esteja errado.

Você quer passar informações via POST ou GET.
Já considerou utilizar o Ajax para isto?

```
$.ajax({
        url:'minha_pagina.php',
        type:'POST',
        data:'info=' + info
});
```

O que especificamente você quer fazer?

Neste link existe algo semelhante: [Jquery document.location.reload() doesn't work correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15075447/jquery-document-location-reload-doesnt-work-correctly)

Comment: Então, nesse meu caso estou passando informações ora por get, ora por post. Estou fazendo todos os tratamentos e esta funcionando.

Comment: @MarceloDiniz Como os colegas acima falaram, quando é executado um refresh os campos de formulários são limpos. Aí você teria que fazer como no Link que postei ali, adicionar os parâmetros ao link conforme for executando.